# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serializeArray' of null

Tags: javascript

I am testing a similar example as mentioned on [w3schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_serializearray) :

So, I have the following in one of my php file :

```
    <form >
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
    </form>
```

Here's my button related code in the same php file somewhere below the above form:

```
<div id="submitParagraphID">
    <img src="myImage.png" alt="Success" /> Thank you for submitting your request.
</div>
<div class="row"style="margin-top: 15px;" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="downloadSetsButtonDiv">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitUsingjQuery()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my simple javascript function in a separate JS file:

```
function submitUsingjQuery(){  
            $("#submitParagraphID").show("fast");
            console.log("Is console log printing?");
            alert("Is control reaching here?");
            var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
}
```

Observations :

1) `$("#submitParagraphID").show("fast");` works fine.

2) `console.log("Is console log printing?");` doesn't prints any thing.

3) `alert("Is control reaching here?");` works fine and shows alert box

4)`var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();` keeps on throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serializeArray' of null`

Comment: What you get for console log `$("form").length`? Zero?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7dohbytj/ looks ok to me, based on your code above, assuming the HTML is all in the same page. Even having it in a separate JS file shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: `$()` shouldn't return `null`. If jQuery finds no match, it returns an empty array. Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @palaѕн when I typed `alert($("form").length);`, I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`. Console logs not working for some reason hence using `alert` to test.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, it is included. I believe that's the reason `$("#submitParagraphID").show("fast");` is working.

Comment: @Dan `console.log()` works fine, but you need to check the console (press F12). Can you create a [mcve]? Because your code works for ADyson and for me.

Comment: It started working fine when I changed `$` to `$testjquery`. I wonder why someone else who worked on the code has used `$testjquery` everywhere and not just `$`. Using  `alert($testjquery("form").length);` showed `42` in alertbox and using `var formdata = $testjquery("form").serializeArray();` didn't throw any error. Console logs still doesn't work for some reason though.

Comment: "Console logs still doesn't work for some reason though. "...console..log doesn't pop anything up on the web page, you understand that? You have to look in the Console which is inside your browser's Developer Tools. On most browsers you open that by pressing F12.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I am talking about Developers console only which opens up after pressing F12. Thanks

Comment: well then it's impossible that your code is not logging and you are not seeing it, assuming that code contains a console.log() is being executed, and the thing being logged actually contains any text or value. And obviously that the console being viewed is the one for the tab containing the relevant page.

Comment: I just tested in IE, it's printing all console logs related statements in the developers console. But nothing is getting printed on chrome's developer tools which is strange.